# Why I can't Access URL When JSON Parsing in Android Studio?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, httphandler

I work an android project. I use MySQL, PHP, Android Studio for this project. I create a server and database. I want to access to server everywhere. So, I take a static IP and I add a port. When I checked this port, I see it's open and I acces this IP everywhere. I try it.

Than, I create a table and php page for JSON values.

My PHP Page returns this:

```
{
  "News": [
    {
      "NewsID": "1",
      "NewsTitle": "A",
      "NewsDesc": "A",
      "NewsImage": "A.jpg",
      "NewsDate": "2019-08-20"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to parse this JSON values in android. I try base HTTP Request and Retrofit 2 but, I don't access URL. I try other urls, they are working. But, when I write my IP address; I take null value. I can't solve this problem. What can I do?

This my HttpHandler class in Java:

```
public class HttpHandler {

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public HttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And I parse with this on my MainActivity class:

```
   HttpHandler hh = new HttpHandler();
   String JSON = hh.makeServiceCall(url);
```

Comment: do you get any exceptions?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, No.

Comment: are you sure? Because 99% cases when the `response` is null is because you get the exception. Try debugging your `makeServiceCall` method

Comment: I guess, my url is started "http" and it will be "https". How can change them?

Comment: `my url is started "http" and it will be "https"` what does this mean?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I access with "http://1.1.1.1/api/NewsJson" but when I try "https://1.1.1.1/api/NewsJson", I take error 403 in browser. I guess, android don't accept http. I can turn http to https but now I take error 403.